# Can't get document from firestore

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

[image]I'm trying to console.log a document from Firestore in a Firebase Cloud Function. Can someone help me with the code ?

```
export const getUser = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const uid = req.query.uid

    corsHandler(req, res, () => {
        onUpdate(res, uid)

    })

})

function onUpdate(res, uid) {
    functions.database.ref(`/profiles/{profileId}`).onUpdate((change, context) => {
        const profileId = uid

        console.log('BEFORE: ', change.before.val())
        res.send('OK')
    })
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We'll need more information to properly help you, including *what specifically is going wrong*. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [Creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work:

```
export const getUser = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const uid = req.query.uid

    corsHandler(req, res, () => {

       admin.firestore().collection('profiles').doc(uid).get()
       .then(snapshot => {
          console.log(snapshot.data())
          res.send('OK')
       })
       .catch(err => {
          console.error('ERROR:', err)
          res.status(500).send(err)
        })

    })

})
```

Note that by having

```
functions.database.ref(`/profiles/{profileId}`).onUpdate()
```

in your `onUpdate` function:

1/ You are using the syntax for the Realtime Database and not for Firestore;

2/ You are setting an event handler in a Cloud Function that is already triggered through an event (being here a call to the HTTPS Cloud Function URL).

Within your HTTPS Cloud Function, you should simply use the Firestore [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#get) method in order to read from the database. No need to set another event handler or any listener: the "one time" database read/query done with `get()` will be triggered each time the HTTPS Function is called.

You may watch this official video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Unfortunately snapshot.val() returns me null.

Comment: Do you have a document with key = uid under profiles? Can you add an export of your database to your post?

Comment: Yes. I just added a screenshot of firebase

Comment: Ok, I understand: in your code you use the code for querying the Realtime database and not Firestore. Let me update my answer.

Comment: It does work very well , thank you very much for your time